# VBA Regular Expression to Match Date

Tags: regex, vba, vbscript

I'm new to Regular Expressions and am having difficulty getting patterns that I find online to work in VBScript/VBA. This one is supposed to return a date found in a string but it fails to find any dates. What does VBScript/VBA do different than other RegEx engines that makes this fail to return a match?

**Edit1**
I removed the ^ and the $ from my pattern. The problem persists.

```
Private Sub TestDate()
    MsgBox RegExDate("cancel on 12/21/2010 ")
End Sub

Private Function RegExDate(s As String) As String
    Dim re, match
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    re.Pattern = "(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))"
    re.Global = True

    For Each match In re.Execute(s)
        MsgBox match.value
        RegExDate = match.value
        Exit For
    Next
    Set re = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks as if your RegEx will only find match if the whole string you pass to it is a date.

Try removing `^` and `$`

Here's your example reworked using a RegEx that will find dates in the mm/dd/yyyy and mm-dd-yyyy formats -

```
Private Sub TestDate()
    MsgBox RegExDate("cancel on 12/21/2010 ")
End Sub

Private Function RegExDate(s As String) As String
    Dim re, match
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    re.Pattern = "(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)[0-9]{2}"
    re.Global = True

    For Each match In re.Execute(s)
        MsgBox match.Value
        RegExDate = match.Value
        Exit For
    Next
    Set re = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Great suggestion but that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a new RegEx in your code sample, not sure if it's too specific though?

Comment: Any explanation on the changes that were needed? Also any ideas on how to make this find (mm/dd/yyyy) or (mm-dd-yyyy)?

Comment: It will already find mm-dd-yyyy, sorry should have put that in the last comment

Comment: be aware, that will also match invalid dates eg. Feb 31st

Answer (score 6):

Why not use RegEx to get the portion of the string that appears to be the date and use the [IsDate](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_isdate.asp) Function to validate it?

```
Function FormatOutput(s)
    Dim re, match
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    re.Pattern = "[\d]+[\/-][\d]+[\/-][\d]+"
    re.Global = True

    For Each match In re.Execute(s)
        if IsDate(match.value) then
            FormatOutput = CDate(match.value)
            Exit For
        end if
    Next
    Set re = Nothing

End Function
```

The RegEx could be cleared up a bit, but it works for your current example.

Comment: Will this find dates that are separated by dashes? But yeah, testing the string returned is certainly OK in this case.

Comment: Updated the Pattern.  it will match on / or - for date separators.

Comment: Great answer! Always having trouble with regular expressions :-s